# eigenvalues for a large covariance (semi positive) matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix X and I am trying to compute the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix:

```
A = X.dot(np.transpose(X))
val, vec = np.linalg.eigh(A)
```

In my case A is large (about 40k*40k) in which case python crashes. The largest matrix I could get to work was about 10k*10k despite the fact that my machine 56GB of memory. Is there a way to compute the eigenvalues of such a large matrix?

I am using python 3.5 with numpy 1.17.3

Comment: What does it crashes means? Do you get any kind of error message? Did you monitor the memory usage during the calculations?

Comment: I tried it using jupyter and the hub crashed. When I tried running it from the command line I see that the memory is the problem. Any way around it?

Comment: It works for me with using 75% of my 32GB memory... How much free mem do you have before starting the calculations?